# Is there a way to configure ng-bind-html that it renders a string like '</'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, sanitize, ng-bind-html

it seems ng-bind-html is rendering `'</'` like a close tag, so it has been sanitized, and the string has pass through, but it renders as close tag in html, which means nothing shows. for example, 'I find `</` is a good thing', if I bind the string to it, everything after `</` will be cut off, it only shows 'I find' in the web page

(add on)
The problem is actually we were mix-using html encoding and url encoding at the same time, right now, the input from front end is like '`</` is good', then there is a service to encode it, after encoding, it becomes '&lt%2F is good', before it gets into database, it becomes '&lt/ is good', and when we get data back, ng-bind-html picks it up as '`</` is good'. but we have an input field to edit it that's using ng-model, so ng-model picks it up as '$lt/ is good', which is the same as database. so before we edit it, we do a replace() function in the controller, so we temporarily fixed the problem. But still not sure if it's the right way, even in stackoverflow itself, the similar problem exists, you can see the `</` has a grey background, because stackoverflow rich text editor doesn't take it as a normal string, so I made backtick escapes for this particular string to show in the text editor.

Comment: There may be a few things going on here which you may not be accounting for.  For example, you could be dealing with Angular's HtmlSanitization scripts, inhibiting you from arbitrarily injecting HTML etc.  It is hard for me to understand what you are talking about though as you do not have a sample we can work with.  please create one and we can work through it.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for ng-bind instead of ng-bind-html?

Comment: @Fallenreaper you are right, sorry that I didn't provide enough context. The problem is actually we were mix-using html encoding and url encoding at the same time, right now, the input from front end is like '</ is good', then there is a service to encode it, after encoding, it becomes '&lt%2F is good', before it gets into database, it becomes '&lt/ is good', and when we get data back, ng-bind-html picks it up as '</ is good'. but we have an input field to edit it that's using ng-model, so ng-model picks it up as '$lt/ is good', which is the same as database. we fixed it by hardcoding for now

Comment: @StevePak we still need the sanitization part, so we need ng-bind-html

Comment: @XiaoyeYang Hardcoding doesnt sound like the right way.  If you can give us HTML or Component snippets?  We might be able to address the issue.

Comment: @Fallenreaper sorry, by hardcoding, I mean doing a replace() function of that ng-model binded variable in the controller before render. It's an internal app so I will try to mimic part of the code when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `'<'` to `'&lt;'` works as expected:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope,$sce) {
    $scope.text = "I find &lt;/ is a good thing";
    $scope.trust = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.text);
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
   <h2>Using ng-bind-html</h2>
   <p ng-bind-html="trust"></p>
   <h2>Using ng-bind</h2>
   <p ng-bind="text"></p>
</body>
```

For more information, see

- [MDN HTML Reference - Entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity)
- [AngularJS `ng-bind-html` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: Thanks! so as I said to Fallenreaper.The problem is actually we were mix-using html encoding and url encoding at the same time, right now, the input from front end is like '</ is good', then there is a service to encode it, after encoding, it becomes '&lt%2F is good', before it gets into database, it becomes '&lt/ is good', and when we get data back, ng-bind-html picks it up as '</ is good'. but we have an input field to edit it that's using ng-model, so ng-model picks it up as '$lt/ is good', which is the same as database. But your answer definitely helps!